# Property of complex borel measures with absolutely convergent Fourier series (Wiener algebra)

Tags: measure-theory, fourier-analysis

Let $\mu$ be a complex Borel measure on the circle $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ with
$$
\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \lvert\hat{\mu}(n)\rvert < \infty.
$$
How does it follow that $d\mu(x) = f(x) dx$ for $f$ continuous on the circle?

I suppose it is due to the fact that the hypothesis is equivalent to $\mu \ast D_n$ being continuous and converging uniformly, where $D_n$ the the Dirichlet kernel. But how do I know that $\mu \ast D_n$ relates to $\mu$ in any way with no convergence results?

This is the start of an exercise (1.2) from the beginning of *Classical and Multilinear Harmonic Analysis* Vol 1. by Muscalu and Schlag.

More generally, I am somewhat struggling with the use of complex Borel measures in statements where I am accustomed to seeing functions that are $L^p$ with respect to some positive measure. I understand that they are related via Radon-Nikodyn, but I struggle with how to think about certain statements: in particular, the convolution of a continuous function and a complex Borel measure, among others. Any advice/reading recommendations on getting more familiar with the heavy use of these measures and their interaction with functions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $$f(t)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \hat\mu(n)e^{int}.$$The series converges uniformly so $f$ is continuous. The uniform convergence also shows that $$\hat f(n)=\hat\mu(n).$$So uniqueness (for complex measures) shows that $\mu=f$, or more carefully $d\mu=f\,dt$.

If you don't buy the uniqueness for complex measures bit:

Lemma: If $\nu$ is a complex measure and $\hat\nu(n)=0$ for all $n$ then $\nu=0$.

Proof: $\int p\,d\nu=0$ for every trigonometric polynomial $p$. Hence by uniform approximation $\int \phi\,d\nu=0$ for every continuous function $\phi$. Hence $\nu=0$ (gotta assume we know *something*).

Comment: Thanks. If you don't mind, do you know how an expression $f \ast \mu$ is interpreted? Where $f$ is continuous and $\mu$ is a complex Borel measure. And by extension we can have $f \in L^p$.

Comment: "f continuous and \mu a complex Borel measure" is not enough to make the convolution exist. If $f$ is continuous and bounded then $$f*\mu(x)=\int\tau_x \,d\mu,$$where $\tau_xf(t)=f(t-x)$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich why do we need uniform convergence for $\hat f(n) = \hat \mu(n)$? I see that the Fourier coefficients are computable from the series expression (and interchange of limits being justified by uniformity), but can't we just conclude that from uniqueness of Fourier coefficients?

Comment: @Nitin I didn't say we _needed_ _uniform_ convergence. We're given that the sum converges uniformly. "can't we just conclude that from uniqueness of Fourier coefficients?" I don't know exactly what argument you have in mind - you're assuming what, and want to conclude what?